# postgresql truncate cascade tables with wildcard

Tags: database, postgresql, wildcard, truncate, cascade

is it possible to truncate and cascade tables with using a wildcard?

```
SELECT format('TRUNCATE TABLE %I CASCADE;', tablename)
FROM   pg_tables WHERE tableowner = 'XXX';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can if you wrap it in an anonymous code block and add a loop:

```
do $$

  declare
    tr pg_tables%rowtype;
  begin
    for tr in
      select * from pg_tables WHERE tableowner = 'XXX';
    loop
      execute format('TRUNCATE TABLE %I.%I CASCADE;', tr.schemaname, tr.tablename);
    end loop;
  end;

$$;
```

Also (as above), I'd add the schema name just to avoid any potential unintended consequences.

Comment: how do I execute this? only way I know is to make a query. How do I go about introducing this script to my database?

Comment: as @EmilioPlatzer said above, you can just execute it as-is, as you would any other SQL command -- from psql, PgAdmin, or anywhere you would normally execute SQL.  Give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

In this way you obtain one single TRUNCATE TABLE with all table_names and then they will be **procesed together**

```
do $$
  declare
    names text;
    my_sql text;
  begin
    select string_agg(format('%I.%I', schemaname, tablename), ', ')
      into names
      from pg_tables 
      where tableowner = 'XXX';
    if names<>'' then
      my_sql = 'TRUNCATE TABLE '||names||' CASCADE';
      execute my_sql;
    end if;
  end;
$$;
```

Comment: how do I execute this? only way I know is to make a query. How do I go about introducing this script to my database?

Comment: That is a query. If you can write INSERT, DELETE or UPDATE you can write DO (unless you are working inside a framework that prohibits it)